# Hiding pivot attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know you can hide an entire pivot table as such

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
```

How do you hide a specific field within pivot table, like

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot.created_at'];
```

The above does not work from what I've tested

Comment: try `$this->addHidden($attributes);`  Can you even provide output of model so we can see how you are getting various attributes.

Comment: Are you using `withPivot()` on your relationship methods to return only the columns you want?

Comment: Currently I have `public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Order', 'payments_to_orders', 'payment_id', 'order_id')->withPivot('amount')->withTimestamps();
}` and when doing `$payment->load(['orders','method'])` I am getting back `"pivot": {
"payment_id": "1",
"order_id": "7",
"amount": "60.00",
"created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
"updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}` I want to hide `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: remove ->withTimestamps();

Comment: wait let me try this at my machine

Comment: if I remove `->withTimestamps();` it will not save timestamps which I need. I need to save, but hide for json output. To clarify relationships, here are the tables: `orders`,`payments`,`payments_to_orders` (the latter contains an `amount` field). So 1 payment can pay for a part of an order or many orders.

Comment: @MonOve Check and try my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After so much trying and looking into [source of Laravel Model](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), i finally got it achieved.

Please put following method at your Model.

```
/**
 * Convert the model instance to an array.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray()
{
    $attributes = $this->attributesToArray();
    $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $this->relationsToArray());
    unset($attributes['pivot']['created_at']);
    return $attributes;
}
```

This solves the purpose.

Comment: it works but is a far cry from what I would like Laravel to do

Comment: Have to agree... it works, but it's awful. Will have to use it as there isn't an elegant way to achieve the same result.